# XAMMP: Cant view php file from browser

Tags: php, apache, xampp

So i made a simple php file to echo hello in the htdocs folder, I have xammp running with apache and mysql running.  I have changed the port from `80` to `1234` in the apache config file.  On my google chrome browser I have tried/typed in the following:

```
localhost/test.php
localhost/test/php:1234
127.0.0.1:1234
http//:localhost/test.php
```

I get a blank page with the following error:
This site can't be reached

```
127.0.0.1 refused to connect
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: That sounds like Apache isn't listening on the port you think it is. Have you restarted Apache since the change? Could you post your Apache configuration?

Comment: so did that help you lucky or are you still having an issue>?

Answer (score 1):

you want to go http://url:port/page so you should try

`http://localhost:1234/test.php`

Answer (score 0):

After changing your port, you page should listen to the new port.

Try this http://localhost:1234/youpage.php